# DetailsView paging is enabled/causing postback when the textbox used for searching has invalid content and client-side shows the error

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, detailsview

Very new to ASP.Net development so hope this is not too much of a silly question.

I have a web page (framework 3.5) with a DetailsView control which is bound to sql and reads records via a Stored Procedure. AllowPaging = true on the control because more than one record may be found.

It uses a text box control - value entered by the user - to pass to the SP.

The text box has a Regular expression validation control which highlights when input is invalid.

I am doing as follows:

1. enter valid data in text box and hit 'enter' - records are found so DetailsView shows me the first record plus numbered paging buttons (correct)
2. change the value in the textbox to something invalid, and tab out of textbox - validation control highlights the error (correct)
3. press 'enter' - nothing happens, invalid (correct)
4. click on one of the numbered paging buttons in the DetailsView - postback occurs. The validation control has not prevented the paging taking place. I would like to prevent any postback/response other than forcing the user to correct the invalid data in the text box.

Am sure there should be an easy way to handle this and have tried various options but not getting there. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the markup for validation control as well as the textboxes?

Comment: Make property of detailview - CauseValidation  true

Answer (score 1):

Basically here validation doesn't happens when you click on any numbered paging buttons of DetailsView.

Preventing even complete postback requires that page checks for Client side validation. Also
to make the validation occur on server side,call `Page.Validate()` in `PageIndexChanging` event of DetailsView. If the page is Not valid prevent the paging from happening.

**NOTE I:** You can call `Page.Validate()` inside  `Page_Load` event also. It's not necessary that you should call this event in `DetailsView.PageIndexChanging` event only.

**NOTE II:** in case you just want only to prevent paging to occur and don't want to use  `PagerTemplates`, use server side validation. A postback will always happen, although if Page is not Valid, Paging will not occur.

Start by using `<PagerTemplates>` for paging in DetailsView and set the `CausesValidation` attribute to true for the pager buttons. The below settings of `CommandName` & CommandArgument will automatically take care of your Paging. ***[See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.pagertemplate.aspx)***.

```
<pagertemplate>
<asp:LinkButton id="PreviousButton"
                    text=" Previous_"
                    CommandName="Page"
                    CommandArgument="Prev"  CausesValidation="true"
                    runat="Server"/>
 <asp:LinkButton id="NextButton"
                    text="Next_"
                    CommandName="Page"
                    CommandArgument="Next" CausesValidation="true"
                    runat="Server"/> 
</pagertemplate>
```

Markup of DetailsView:

```
<asp:DetailsView  runat="server" ID="EmpDetails"
     OnPageIndexChanging="EmpDetails_PageIndexChanging" ... />
```

Event Handler

```
protected void EmpDetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, DetailsViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate();
        if (!Page.IsValid)
            e.Cancel = true;// Prevent the paging 

    }
```